# How to setup dbt using docker containers on Windows 10

Tags: docker, docker-desktop, dbt

After reading Dbt documentation, I've had a hard time to figure out how to install dbt-core (or any other packages i.e. dbt-postgres, dbt-snowflake, etc) on Windows 10.

I have Docker Desktop installed, running a couple of containers already (mostly nodeJS containers, and Kafka). However, it was hard to understand how I would have those new Dbt containers available in my Docker Desktop Console.

I can see docker images were installed properly

```
$docker image ls
REPOSITORY                      TAG          IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
**ghcr.io/dbt-labs/dbt-core       1.2.1        802a0d70aedc   4 weeks ago    538MB**
**ghcr.io/dbt-labs/dbt-bigquery   1.2.latest   b7502bcd3b35   2 months ago   559MB**
...
postgres                        latest       f8dd270e5152   7 weeks ago    376MB
dpage/pgadmin4                  latest       d13c9d7d0193   2 months ago   382MB
wurstmeister/kafka              latest       a692873757c0   4 months ago   468MB
wurstmeister/zookeeper          latest       3f43f72cb283   3 years ago    510MB
```

Does anyone know how to I them to the Desktop Console?

Comment: Unless you really know Docker and/or have a reason to use it, it's probably much easier to just [install Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) and then `pip install dbt-core` on Windows 10. Personally I use WSL2, so I can run Ubuntu on Windows, which is amazing, but is a whole different can of worms.

Comment: Indeed. Much easier that way. I'd installed dbt adapters via pip before, I've tried via docker. Perfectionism

Answer (score 0):

I finally was able to pull the image. To add a container in the Docker desktop, I just needed to actually run it.

However, running a dbt-core container in docker, it returns an error:
right after I start the container it stops and returns exit(1), as per the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently on Windows 10 and use a Docker image for my dbt project without needing WSL. Below is my Dockerfile and requirements.txt file with dbt-core and dbt-snowflake but feel free to swap the packages you need.

In my repo, my dbt project is in a folder at the root level named dbt.

**requirements.txt**

```
dbt-core==1.1.0
dbt-snowflake==1.1.0
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/docker/library/python:3.8-slim-buster

COPY . /dbt

# Update and install system packages
RUN apt-get update -y && \
  apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y -q \
  git libpq-dev python-dev && \
  apt-get clean && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# Install dbt
RUN pip install -U pip
RUN pip install -r dbt/requirements.txt
# TEMP FIX due to dependency updates. See https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/issues/4745
RUN pip install --force-reinstall MarkupSafe==2.0.1

# Install dbt dependencies
WORKDIR /dbt
RUN dbt deps

# Specify profiles directory
ENV DBT_PROFILES_DIR=.dbt

# Expose port for dbt docs
EXPOSE 8080
```

And then you can build and run it (I personally put both of these commands in a dbt_run.sh file and run with bash dbt_run.sh):

```
docker build -t dbt_image .
docker run \
-p 8080:8080 \
--env-file .env \
-it \
--mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)",target=/dbt \
dbt_image bash
```

If you make changes to your dbt project while the container is running they will be reflected in the container which makes it great for developing locally. Hope this helps!